# use a fetch response in a second fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a function with two fetch requests. The first fetch request returns an array of objects which contains ACCTNO. I'm trying  to use the returned ACCTNO is a second request. However I'm not having any success. I'm also trying to refer to this.state.buildUrl, as I need buildUrl to render in a view but I get the error saying this.setState is not a function or undefined. How can I use the first fetch response in my second request?

```
  componentDidMount() {


  var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/combined';
   var result = fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json(); 
  }).then(function(data) {
    var ACCTNO =  data[0].ACCOUNT;

  var FormData = require('form-data');
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('businessId', '123456');
    form.append('login', 'SAFConnectUser');
    form.append('password', '123445678');
    form.append('billingAccountNumber', ACCTNO);
    form.append('signOffURL', 'fd');
    form.append('timeOutURL', 'fd');

  fetch('https://collectpay-uat.princetonecom.com/otp/namevaluepair/submitSingleSignOn.do', {

      method: 'POST',

      body: form
    }).then((response) => response.text()).then((res) => {
      if (res.error) {
        console.log(res.error)
      }

      console.log(res)


      var fields = res.split('|');

      var getUrl = fields[3];
      var buildUrl = getUrl.slice(14)


      // Getting error that setState is not a function?
      this.setState({buildUrl})


    console.log(buildUrl)
    console.log(ACCTNO)  

    })

  })

}






  render() {



    return (
 <WebView
        source={{uri: this.state.buildUrl}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />

    );
  }
}

export default acidirect;
```

Comment: I see two requests. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly. I think the issue might be that your data array is empty. Why not try to print "data" and see what it looks like?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your functions to fat arrow functions so they can refer to `this`:

```
class acidirect {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8080/combined', {
      method: 'get',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var ACCTNO = data[0].ACCOUNT;
      var FormData = require('form-data');
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('businessId', '123456');
      form.append('login', 'SAFConnectUser');
      form.append('password', '123445678');
      form.append('billingAccountNumber', ACCTNO);
      form.append('signOffURL', 'fd');
      form.append('timeOutURL', 'fd');

      fetch('https://collectpay-uat.princetonecom.com/otp/namevaluepair/submitSingleSignOn.do', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
      })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(res => {
        var fields = res.split('|');
        var getUrl = fields[3];
        var buildUrl = getUrl.slice(14);
        this.setState({buildUrl});
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: this.state.buildUrl}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default acidirect;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Error while updating property 'source ' of a view managed by: RTCWebView

Comment: Remove the WebView for now. Just concentrate that you can make second fetch with the data from the first and that you can `setState` after second one finishes.

Comment: When I `console.log(this.state.buildUrl)` I get undefined

Comment: Dont `console.log` it right after `this.setState({buildUrl});` since it is not available there yet. Render a `<Text>{this.state. buildUrl}</Text>` so you can see the state. Also try to `console.log` this part `var buildUrl = getUrl.slice(14);` if you even got a value for `buildUrl` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set your response from first fetch in state as

```
 fetch('/url',{credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(this.setSomeState);
```

Now set your state

```
 setSomeState: function(response) {

    this.setState({
        array: response
    });
  },
```

Now you can get it anywhere using

```
  this.state.array
```